# OpengGL - SOIL texture all black

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

I linked, included, and did everything necessary to use SOIL and it's functions.

I load the texture like so in init():

```
void initRendering() {

std::string vertexInputString="exampleVS.txt";
std::string fragmentInputString="exampleFS.txt";

//create new shader
InitializeProgram(shaderOne, readFiletoString(vertexInputString), readFiletoString(fragmentInputString));

//enables/disables
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
//glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
//glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

//states
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

//load textures
image = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
    "resources/wood.png",
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
    SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
);
if( 0 == image ){printf( "SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result());}


//start shader
glUseProgram(shaderOne);
}
```

For simplicity the wood.png is a 256x256 png texture and loads without an error message.

Here is where i draw the textured quad:

```
glPushMatrix();
        glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0,1.0f);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image);
        //glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);  
        //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_DECAL);
        //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_DECAL);
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);  // when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest mipmap
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // when texture area is large, bilinear filter the first mipmap
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);  // texture should tile
        //glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(-50.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f,1.0f); glVertex3f(-50.0f, 10.0f, -50.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f); glVertex3f(50.0f, 10.0f, -50.0f);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(50.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f);

        glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

The result is simply an all black texture instead of a wood texture:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your texture loading function generate mipmaps? I notice that you commented out all your `glTexParameteri` calls. You may need some of them. If the texture does not have mipmaps, you'll probably want to set MAG_FILTER to LINEAR and MIN_FILTER to NEAREST, or something similar. At least I would try those values, and see if the texture becomes non-black.

Comment: I tried that with no different result. It turns out the black was just from the last glColor call i made. Still don't know why my texture isnt appearing.

Comment: With certain `glTexEnvf` modes, `glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0,1.0f);` will make texture render black. Try using `glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);` instead.

Comment: Solved! I had my shader on when i was rending the textured quad, and since my shader doesnt support textures(yet), the color of my quad was just whatever the most recent glColor was.